# Как отредактировать переменные среды в python

Tags: python, python-2.x

Такой вот код:

```
import os
os.environ['path'] += r';C:\ProgramData\boot'
```

Выполняется без ошибок, но в path ничего не добавляется, почему?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [How to set environment variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5971312/6166540)

Comment: Т.е примерно такой код должен получиться? import os
path = os.environ["path"]
os.environ["path"] = r"C:\ProgramData\boot" + path

Comment: `os.environ['path'] += r';C:\ProgramData\boot'

Comment: Странно, не добавилось

Comment: Если задача установить переменную окружения, то отредактируте вопрос с учетом того, что получилось (или не получилось) при использовании `os.envoron`. _Странно, не добавилось_ - укажите, как проверяли.

Comment: Задача отредактировать переменную %path%, вставил ваш код, запустил, пишу в консоле echo %path%  ничего не добавилось.

Comment: Еще раз повторюсь, отредактируйте вопрос и заголовок в соответсвии с задачей.

Comment: `print(os.environ['path'])` до обновления и после выводит одинаковые строки?

Comment: Запустил код, все работает, все добавляется.

Comment: После обновления выводит разные строки, но если в системе echo %path% прописать, нету там этого пути + приложение которое по этому пути не могу запустить с консоли.

Comment: Тут просто нужно понимать, что добавляется не в системную переменную PATH, которую вы выводите через ``echo %path%`` в ее копию, которая используется в питонской консоли. Добавить в глобальную переменную так не получится.

Comment: Вообще задача стоит такая: в папке C:\ProgramData\boot приложение и мне надо как то его запустить по другому пути например с D:\ в консоле пишу start например proc.exe, нашел решение через переменные среды но что-то не получается.

Comment: Так меняйте переменную в консоли, оттуда же запускайте приложение. Зачем еще что-то?

Comment: Мне надо чтобы сценарий менял, а через subprocess не получается.

Comment: Скрипт запускается в дочернем процессе, он изменяет свое окружение, а не родительское.

Comment: А можно как то изменить родительское?

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
cmd = 'wmic environment where name="PATH" set variablevalue="C:\Temp;%PATH%'
os.system(cmd)
```

Сегодня тоже столкнулся с такой задачей, здесь например меняется PATH.
В Win есть команда SETX

```
import os
name = 'abc'
value = 'zzz'
os.system(f'SETX {name} {value}')
```

Comment: Важно отметить, что нужно открыть новый сеанс командной строки, чтобы увидеть новое значение.